# How to launch MuleServer in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, mule

I'm trying to launch an existing mule server project in Intellij.
I followed [these](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Working+with+an+IDE) instructions and after a number fo tweaks to my build path, have worked my way to the error below:

```
2013-04-26 10:55:26,632 ERROR [main] [MuleServer] A Fatal error has occurred while the server was running: org.mvel2.ast.Function.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;[C[CILorg/mvel2/ParserContext;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mvel2.ast.Function.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;[C[CILorg/mvel2/ParserContext;)V
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELFunctionAdaptor.<init>(MVELFunctionAdaptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguageContext.declareFunction(MVELExpressionLanguageContext.java:229)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.StaticVariableResolverFactory.<init>(StaticVariableResolverFactory.java:32)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.initialise(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:99)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.initialise(DefaultExpressionManager.java:611)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.initialise(DefaultMuleContext.java:223)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:192)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracked this down to a conflict between different versions of mvel2. Seems they changed the signature of Function() from 2.0.19:

```
Function(String name, char[] parameters, char[] block, int fields, ParserContext pCtx)
```

to 2.1.beta1:

```
Function(String name, char[] expr, int start, int offset, int blockStart, int blockOffset, int fields, ParserContext pCtx)
```